# Failed to open stream and twitter won´t load

Tags: php, twitter

Severity: Warning  Message:

file_get_contents(https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?user_id=432572114&include_entities=true&include_rts=true&count=3): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!

HTTP/1.0 410 Gone  Filename: controllers/ibiza.php
Line Number: 42

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-final-dates

API v1 is no longer available.